# updated_time not working FQL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

```
SELECT post_id, actor_id, target_id, message,comments,likes,attachment,description,action_links,created_time,updated_time FROM stream WHERE source_id =me() and updated_time>1322379277
```

Above is my fql.
But I'm getting nothing despite there are posts after this updated_time

Comment: It's a bug.
[related page](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/316607451683448?browse=search_4eed342fe60cc5287505019)

Comment: Looks like you're missing `and`: `WHERE source_id =me()  AND updated_time>1322379277`

Comment: No it was mistake, but still not working..it looks bug

Comment: There's a bug reported: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/427508997279856